# JSON.parse throws error

Tags: javascript, json

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>        
        var str = "{ 'foo': 'bar' }";
        var json = JSON.parse(str);
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

This code throws an error on the second variable statement. Why?
(Chrome says "unexpected token ILLEGAL", Firefox says "JSON.parse")

Comment: Have a look at the [JSON specification](http://json.org/) :)

Comment: @Felix Dude, that spec is to long. I don't have time for this. :p

Comment: Vidas: It's images :-P ;) I just wanted to show, how a string is defined in JSON.

Comment: @Felix It's possibly the shortest web-standard ever :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're supposed to use double, not single quotes:

```
 var str = '{ "foo": "bar" }';
 var json = JSON.parse(str); 
 json['foo']
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was easier to just use String() on the object before calling JSON.parse()

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.foo;
var encoded = JSON.parse(String(retrievedObject));
```